# How to test for nested element?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test for whether or not an element is in the HTML.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="title-text">
  <h1>
    Event Timeline
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="alert-section" *ngIf="showError">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs">
      <p>Error</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="timeline-section" *ngIf="events">                     
  <step-navigation [sequential]="true" activeAccent="accent-0-dark" incompleteAccent="accent-0-dark">
    <p>Test timeline</p>
  </step-navigation>
</div>
```

I want to test for the existence of the `step-navigation` element. How do I do this? I've already tried

```
  it('should have the timeline-section element', () => {
    const timelineSectionDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div step-navigation'));
    const timelineSectionElement = timelineSectionDebugElement.nativeElement;

    expect(timelineSectionElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

but it can't find that element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be done like is shown in the original post.

Since the element is inside `ngIf`, `events` should exist and be truthy, and the query should be performed *after* `events` was set and `fixture.detectChanges()` was called.

Comment: Thank you for your help!